# RavenDB Domain Model

Tags: domain-driven-design, ravendb

I'm building my first small RavenDB application and I'm wondering if I'm approaching things correctly when building my domain model.

I've got a list of countries which I want to use in multiple places in my model. Typically in the past I would have created a database table to store the countries and a country object which looked a little like this:

```
public class Country{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string CountryName {get;set;}
}
```

When I went to use the country class I would have held an instance of it inside another object for example:

```
public class Shop{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Country InCountry {get;set;}
}
```

Or

```
public class Customer{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
    public Country CountryOfResidence {get;set;}
}
```

And so on and so forth. Am I correct in thinking that what I should now be doing is storing the Id of the country in the `Shop` and `Customer` classes so they would now look like this:

```
public class Shop{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
}

public class Customer{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
    public int CountryOfResidenceId {get;set;}
}
```

When I go to pull these from the database I can then use the includes feature of the Raven API to get the related country object albeit it's in a seperate object and I can't for example do `myCustomer.Country.Name`.

Obviously this is a very contrived example but I really just want to check that I'm not barking up totally the wrong tree before carrying on down this route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't properly used a document DB (yet), but my thoughts on your question are:

- You shouldn't bend your domain model in order to fit the needs of your persistence implementation, but if there was ever an opportunity to keep your aggregate design completely persistent ignorant, I would have thought it would be when using a document database.
- If the country object only consists of a name, then it's most likely a [Value Object](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-entities-and-value-objects.aspx) and doesn't even require an ID. Value objects are immutable, so if a shop's country changes you just replace the whole object. There's no need to reference an ID because it doesn't matter that multiple aggregates/entities are referencing the same value.
- Regarding child entities: they only serve a purpose within the scope of an Aggregate, meaning you shouldn't have the same entity existing within multiple aggregates. So I would have thought, again, store the entire object and not a reference to an ID.
- Referencing other aggregates is different. This is where you want to reference by ID. This [article](http://dddcommunity.org/sites/default/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_2.pdf) explains why.

Comment: While I completely agree with your first point, I've been criticized for trying to keep my domain model persistent-ignorant when using RavenDB. I think the RavenDB gurus will tell you to structure your domain model to fit RavenDB. See http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/05/why-i-left-ravendb.html and http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-domain-model-pure-with-ravendb.html.

Comment: Well it seems to me document databases are actually better geared for a model that's persistence ignorant than RDMS' are. If you follow my points above (which I believe is how you're supposed to design aggregates) you can simply save each aggregate without having to worry about fetching child entities by ID. My main point is: **if you've designed your aggregates properly, you should only ever need to fetch and save the aggregate and never fetch child entities separately.

Comment: Also - in that first link you've provided, I disagree with pretty much all of what he's said. Read the comment on the blog by Chris Marisic. I share his feelings on this post.

Comment: Thanks guys, some very interesting reading material above. I guess I'm just trying to get used to thinking in a slightly different way.